# Does Silverlight use Presentation Host?

Tags: silverlight, xbap

I deal mostly with XBAP,

Q1.XBAP normally uses the PresentationHost.exe to get the work done,What does SilverLight use?

Q2.Are there considerable differences in moving from XBAP to  SilverLight ? (Experience Based or fact based answers?)

Can somebody give me a rundown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XBAP is the regular .NET framework exposed (as WPF/XAML) in the browser; Silverlight is a much reduced framework, focusing on things like UI/media/etc. But with the advantage of cross-patform support, and (with the next version) allowing the client to take it out-of-browser.

The XAML is similar, but is not a strict subset/superset; so you can't always translate "as is" in either direction; it will also be easier to go Silverlight-to-WPF/XBAP

With Silverlight 3 on the horizon, I'm not sure I'd bother looking too hard at XBAP myself... if I wanted the full .NET, I'd go WPF/ClickOnce.

And I'm pretty sure Silverlight doesn't use presentation host...

Comment: XBAP is not so hard,WPF on the browser that is what xbap is.
WPF/ClickOnce does not run from a browser!

Comment: Your point being? If I wanted browser, I'd go Silverlight. If I wanted full .NET, I'd go WPF via ClickOnce... that's my view.

Comment: Then what is XAML Browser Applications for ?

Comment: They have their uses - a good discussion of each is given in the answers here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b5cd66fc-4cb5-4f26-8668-130c71b74762

Comment: I just stress that: "browser" should usually mean "cross platform"... and XBAP *isn't*. Silverlight *is*. So for a rich browser app, Silverlight would be my default. And is it really important to run WPF in the browser? What difference would ClickOnce make?

Comment: Well when you develop LOB applications and you don't want to go to 10 PC and tell the stupid user to install something then you can just tell them open you browser and type that and phew...

Comment: That is the entire point of ClickOnce too, but with advantages such as local caching, dedicated storage, etc - and fewer browser dependencies. A ClickOnce ".application" can be launched from a browser too.